# Android Bluetooth LE Scanning Background Location Permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I have an app, which implements Bluetooth LE Scanning (by extending `BroadcastReceiver`) to identify when the device is nearby a beacon.

I am experiencing some unexpected behaviour when testing on Android 10 & 11 with `targetSDK = 30`. I understand that in API 29 (Android 10) the background location permission was introduced and that this permission in required for Bluetooth LE Scanning.

However, when I test my app on Android 10 the scanning functionality works correctly without the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission in my manifest. It identifies a nearby beacon if the app is in the foreground, the background or closed.

When I test my app on Android 11 the scanning functionality only works if the device is with range of a beacon and the app is brought from the background into the foreground. It doesn't work if the app is in the background or running in the foreground, only in this transition state.
If I add the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission in my manifest and request this permission at runtime (in the incremental fashion Google enforce) then as long as the user has given at least foreground permissions then the scanning functionality works as expected.

I'm a bit confused by this behaviour specifically:

1. If the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission was added in API 29 then why am I not seeing the behaviour I'm seeing on Android 11 on my Android 10 device?
2. Why do I need the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission when even if a user only gives me foreground permissions (i.e. doesn't select 'Allow All The Time') then it still works and why is this needed for it to work in the foreground also?